# Redirect URL in php

Tags: php, url, redirect, web

I am doing a shopping cart using php, mysql and my payment integration is with CCAvenue. Everything is done except redirecting URL with . It redirects to a specified URL but not capturing the order ID. The sample code is as below

//from checkout page

```
$orderID=100 (unique ID fetched from database)
$orderID="AB".$orderID; // Prefixing alphabet to the orderID
```

//Now $orderID would be AB100, I printed and checked, it outputs the same.

```
echo '<form method="POST" name="customerData" action="ccavRequestHandler.php">';
echo <input type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value="http://mywebsite.com/success.php?orderno="'.$orderID.'"/>'; 
echo '<input type="submit" name="subOrder" value="Confirm and Pay"/>';             
echo '</form>';
```

//submitting the above form will go to ccavRequestHandler.php and store orderID and other details of the customer such as customer name, address etc that I haven't mentioned here.

//while redirecting to merchant's website the URL should be http://mywebsite.com/success.php?orderno=AB100

//from success page, I am trying to get the orderID back from the URL through $_GET method

//The success.php code is as below

```
$selItem=0;
  if(isset($_GET["orderno"])) {
    $selItem='KP'.$_GET["orderno"];     
    echo "<br>";                                                
    $squery_images= "select * from orders where order_id=$selItem";
  }
```

But the issue is, in the URL I am getting

```
http://mywebsite.com/success.php?orderno=
```

instead of

```
http://mywebsite.com/success.php?orderno=AB100
```

Because of it i am unable to get the orderID. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please help me to fix it.

Comment: What does it show if you `echo` the `$orderid` and `die()`. Is it empty? or does it print the orderid?

Comment: echo $orderid; shows AB100 in the checkout page, which is correct. But only in the success page it shows nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line

```
echo <input type="hidden" name="redirect_url"
      value="http://mywebsite.com/success.php?orderno="'.$orderID.'"/>';
```

by

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="redirect_url"
      value="http://mywebsite.com/success.php?orderno='.urlencode($orderID).'/>';
```

Embed variables to URLs using `urlencode` and use proper append operators to build the link. You used `orderno="'.$orderID.'"` which will be converted at runtime to `orderno="AB1290"`.

Comment: Hi, I changed single quotes and double quotes in the URL orderno='.$orderID.'"/>'; and it works

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
 echo "<input type='hidden' name='redirect_url' value='http://mywebsite.com/success.php?orderno=' ".$orderID." />";
```

Comment: tried this. did not work. still having the same problem